# MySQL Error 1215 - Can't add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have a table `users` formatted as follows

```
---------+------------+---------+-------+---------+--------+
  Field  |   type     |    NULL |  Key  |  Deault | Extra  |
------------------------------------------------------------
user_id  | varchar(50)|     NO  |   PRI |  NULL   |        |
```

I also have a table `history` formatted as follows:

```
---------+------------+---------+-------+---------+--------+
  Field  |   type     |    NULL |  Key  |  Deault | Extra  |
------------------------------------------------------------
trans_id | int(11)    |     NO  |   PRI |  NULL   |auto_inc|
------------------------------------------------------------
  id     |varchar(50) |    NO   |       | NULL    |        |
```

When I run the following command I get an `error code 1215: cannot add foreign key constraint.`

```
ALTER TABLE history
ADD FOREIGN KEY (id)
REFERENCES users(user_id)
```

I want to ensure that if an entry is inserted into `history` that the `id` inserted matches a `user_id` in `users`.
What must I do to make `users.user_id` a foreign key for `history.id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, but your datatypes have to match exactly for that to work. Since it doesn't work, you are most likely using different collations for your varchar-columns.

Collations are not displayed when you use `describe`, so use `show create table users` and `show create table history` to check, and then adjust one of your collations so they match each other.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that history.id is not indexed. In order to add a foreign key constraint, the particular column must be indexed.

In your history create script (if you are willing to re-create the tables), before adding the constraint you can type:

```
INDEX 'id_index' ('id', ASC)
```

Or to alter the current table just type:

```
CREATE INDEX id_index
ON history(id,ASC)
```

The "ASC" means it will be indexed in ascending order.

You can read more about indexing here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

You can read about foreign keys in MySQL here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Also, just to be thorough, ensure that you are not trying to use "id" as a foreign key more than once, as foreign key names must be unique.